# Locales working partially on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, internationalization

I deployed my application at Heroku, written in Ruby on Rails. I've made the following configuration to read the locales directory, at config/application.rb:

```
# The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
config.i18n.default_locale = :pt
```

The directory structure is below:

```
config
    locales
        defaults
            en.yml
            pt.yml
        models
            my_model
                en.yml
                py.yml
            my_model_2
                en.yml
                py.yml
            ...
        views
            my_view_1
                en.yml
                py.yml
            my_view_2
                en.yml
                py.yml
            ...
```

Only the locales stored at defaults/pt.yml are working.

In my development environment, all files are working.

What can be wrong?

Comment: Have you got your available locales set to only include `:pt`? ie: `I18n.available_locales = [:pt]` in some initializer file?

Comment: Tried right now. In local server works. In Heroku raises an application error.

Comment: What's the output of the Heroku logs?

Comment: "App Crashed", "Unknown attribute 'available_locales'". I'm thinking about join all the locales information into a single file.

Comment: I have locales in my app configured in a similar way to you and have no issues deploying on Heroku, so it must be something in the config.  One thing that I did notice with your config: try changing your custom config to `config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]`.  The call to `to_s` was something I noticed was missing, so maybe it's worth putting it in and redeploying.

Comment: Your last hint worked. Could you post the answer to community's benefit? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that's missing is a call to `to_s` in the config:

```
config.i18n.load_path += 
  Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
```

should be:

```
config.i18n.load_path += 
  Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
```